# pyinstaller pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Я использую *Designer* и у меня есть два файла: **main.py** и разметка **gui.py**.

В папке с этим проектом я открываю *cmd* и прописываю команду **pyinstaller --onefile main.py**, далее создаются две папки *build* и *dist*.

Исходя из многочисленных гайдов, в *dist* должен быть мой exe`шник, но в ней пусто. Я что-то упускаю?
Как мне собрать приложение, используя **pyinstaller**?

Comment: Имею `pyinstaller -v`  3.4. 
Eсть два файла: `main.py` и разметка `design.py`.
Выполняю  `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` , в `dist` получаю `main.exe`. 
Какая у вас версия pyinstaller? Могу проверить вашу сборку, публикуйте модули.

Comment: Тоже 3.4 версия. В консоли есть некоторые ошибки. Проверьте, пожалуйста https://github.com/hisoyem/s.nick

Comment: У меня все нормально!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня выглядит так:

```
D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov>pyinstaller --onefile main.py
1140 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
1140 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
1140 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
1150 INFO: wrote D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov\main.spec
1150 INFO: UPX is not available.
1180 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\Test\\prov', 'D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\Test\\prov']
1190 INFO: checking Analysis
1190 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existe
1190 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1230 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
1290 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
21135 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
21425 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent
  required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37
22710 INFO: Caching module hooks...
22740 INFO: Analyzing D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov\main.py
23472 INFO: Loading module hooks...
23482 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
23782 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
23782 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
24405 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
24405 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
24885 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
25573 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
26945 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
27359 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
28944 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
28944 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
28963 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
29001 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
33181 INFO: Looking for eggs
33181 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\progr
33181 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
33251 INFO: Warnings written to D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov\build\main\w
33511 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov
33561 INFO: checking PYZ
33561 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
33561 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov\build
35919 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov\build
35958 INFO: checking PKG
35959 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
35962 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
37156 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
37156 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib
 'BINARY')
37166 WARNING: was placed previously at
37166 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib
 'BINARY')
81971 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfu
82011 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python
64bit\run.exe
82011 INFO: checking EXE
82011 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
82021 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
82021 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\_Qt\__Qt\Test\prov\dist\ma
82965 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]